# PHP Cache Strategy - Genius or Sheer Stupidity?

Tags: php, caching

I have a shared hosting with limited capabilities. Memcache and mod_cache are not available to me. I would like to implement my own PHP caching method to cache the results of load-intensive SQL query. Using summary tables in SQL is not an option because the query takes multiple parameters that can assume thousands of different values (it's a statistical system).

My idea is like this:

```
function execQuery($parameter)
{
     $query = "SELECT ....... " . $parameter; //query code has been generated

     $rand = mt_rand(0,10); 
     //no need to check/save expiry dates,generate cache randomly for speed

     if($rand == 0)
     {
           //execute query normally and generate new cache
           $result = mysql_query($query);
           $md5 = md5($query); // the name of the cache file equals the md5 of the query
           $cache_file = fopen("/cache/" . $md5 ."php", "w");
           fwrite($cache_file, $result); // the result is written as php code generating a ready for use result array, code has to be modified I think
           //return the result
     }
     else
     {
            //cache will be used
            $md5 = md5($query);
            if(file_exists("/cache/" . $md5 ."php"))
            {
                  include("/cache/" . $md5 ."php");
                  return $result;
            }
            else
           {
                  //no cache exists, run query normally and generate cache
           }
     }   
}
```

What do you think of this and what are the possible pitfalls? What are the implications of using mt_rand, md5? Do you think they will out-perform a load-intensive query? Are the multiple system file writes worth it (only one write for every 10 hits and can be even increased)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This is better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think its a good question, but I'm not sure its a good question for Stack Overflow. I'm inclined to Leave Open, so I am going to Skip on the Close. If the question is closed, then try [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). They should be able to field this question because Design and Architecture is on-topic in their [Help Center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

File cache is something a lot of system use (probably because a lot of hostings do not provide other caching mechanisms), so generally - it's fine approach. Using rand however, instead of modification date, would not scale well. What if you have a pick of 1000 visits? That means allowing 100 queries to hit the database. So your approach should be based on expiration date. Also, if the query is expensive, whenever you trigger regenration, `touch` the file (so modification date is updated) so other hits do not trigger regenaration as well.

Also you should structure your code in a way that you check if the file exists and if it it not stale at the same step, and have only 1 code for generation:

```
function execQuery($parameter)
{
     $query = "SELECT ....... " . $parameter; //query code has been generated
     $md5 = md5($query); // the name of the cache file equals the md5 of the query
     $cache_file = "/cache/" . $md5 ."php");
     $expire = 600; // seconds


     if(!file_exists($cache_file) || mtime($cache_file) < time() - $expire)
     {
           touch($cache_file);
           //execute query normally and generate new cache
           $result = mysql_query($query);
           $fp = fopen($cache_file, "w");
           fwrite($fp, serialize($result)); // the result is written as php code generating a ready for use result array, code has to be modified I think
           fclose($fp);
     }
     return unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));   
}
```

You should not to save the `resource` variable, returned by mysql_query, but actually fetch the data (otherwise you won't be able to use it).

Generally, the cache works on a principle of single write, multiple reads, so it's not that slow. Sure, it slower than loading in memory, but files that are read a lot would be cached by the OS anyway.